# convert ", " INTO "-" with regular expressions using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to obtain this

> dog-cat-mouse

From each one of those

- dog,cat,mouse
- dog, cat, mouse
- dog cat mouse

What i came up with is 2 preg_replace

```
$str = preg_replace('/[,\s]/', '-', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/--/', '-', $str);
```

works on my local server BUT does not work on production, it gives me

> dog, cat, mouse -> dog--cat--mouse

which is not what I want

Comment: In the example, regex would not be needed, `implode`, `explode` and `trim` are the functions you are looking for.

Comment: @Paul: for the given task regex is will not only be more readable, but faster and less memory-intensive. `preg_replace('/[,\s]+/', '-', $str)`. Show your proposal now?

Comment: It would be something like https://eval.in/206028 but your answer is of course way more elegant.

Comment: And indeed, your solution runs in `0.008s`, mine in `0.012s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `+` quantifier for your `[,\s]` character set.

What it changes is that it now means not "any comma or a whitespace character" but "any consecutive commas and whitespace characters"

```
preg_replace('/[,\s]+/', '-', $str)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/,\h*|\h+/', '-', $str)
```

Use \h instead of \s